# Content in top bar not aligning perfectly?

Tags: vertical-alignment

Basically I have a topbar on a page I'm creating with a fixed positioning. In this div is a container, an a/logo, and a ul. The a/logo is set to float to the left, and the ul is set to float to the right. For some reason, it appears like this: http://puu.sh/ZdS6 with the login button at the top of the bar. Here is my code, can anyone help fix it? http://jsfiddle.net/GPn6K/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not completely understand your question. Do you want you button to be in the right middle? Then try adding the padding-top directly to the ul.

Comment: Well adding a padding top wouldn't exactly be useful because it may appear different on different screen resolutions, I'd prefer a more "natural" way of doing it with a property that is meant to do just that. In simple terms, I want the logo and the "Login" button to be perfectly aligned with one another.

Comment: @Richie, "perfectly aligned" is a little abstract. Do you want both a logo and a button have equal top and bottom margins from the surrounding div? try looking into vertical-align property of css.